# angular-strap popover scope destroyed on hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

Is it possible to avoid destroying popover's scope when hiding popover window?

I have a popover with some custom directive inside. Directive have its own scope. When popover is closed, all the data inside is destroyed.

Is there any way to avoid it?

here is my directive

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['mgcrea.ngStrap']);
app.directive('sum', [function() {
    return  {
        scope: {
            arg1: '@',
            arg2: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'directive.html',
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.doMath = function() {
                $scope.result = parseInt($scope.arg1) + parseInt($scope.arg2);
            }
        }]
    }
}])
```

popover definition

```
<button bs-popover="popover" data-placement="bottom" content-template="test.html" auto-close="true">
    show calculator
</button>
```

and templates

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="test.html">
    <div><sum arg1="1" arg2="2"></sum></div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="directive.html">
    <div>
        <input ng-model="arg1" /> + <input ng-model="arg2" /> = 
        <span ng-bind="result"></span>
    </div>
    <div><button ng-click="doMath()">do the math</button></div>
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L8az1o2q/

Click the button to show the calculator. Make some calculations. When I close the popover and show it again, allthe data disappears.

thanks!